# How to search back in a has_many relationship?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database

For example, a professor has many appointments. So we will have a Professor table and an Appointment table. In the latter one each entry has a foreign key pointing back to an entry in the Professor table, which is a typical has_many relationship in Rails.

My question is, what if I want to query all the appointments a particular professor has? Since there's no back pointer from professors to appointments, that means I have to look up the whole Appointment table and check out those only for this one professor. I know this way works but the efficiency seems bad. So can anyone give me a better solution for back search (I don't know what you call it so I'm making up terms here) in a has_many relationship.

Answer (score 2):

Given this code:

```
class Professor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :professor
end
```

You can use the association in order to query the database, like this:

```
professor = Professor.find(1)
appointments = professor.appointments
```

This will retrieve only the appointments that belong to the specific professor. This code doesn't load the whole appointments table to the memory. It's constructing a query that will only select the required subset of data.

Comment: don't forget to use instance variables to see the appointments in the view :)